# How to call an API with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, routes, adb, port

I'm creating a mobile application in Flutter that I'm testing on physical device(Android). I run my API on a wamp server in local. When I put the route in insomnia, it works and returns me a JSON. However, when I try from this routein my Flutter app. This gives me an error:

[image: Flutter error].

```
final httpResponse = await http.get(Uri.parse('$_baseUrl/motorlocations'));
```

I have tried :

> http://127.0.0.1:80/...
> http://localhost:80/...
> http://10.0.2.2:80/...
> http://myIPV4:80/...

=> If you look at the picture the port is 42794 while I entered port 80.

I've tried this command : `adb -d reverse tcp:42794 tcp:80 (80)` but it isn't working.

Comment: Your phone is connected to the same WIFI ? (same of your PC)

Comment: Please don't post log messages as screenshot. Log messages are pure text, so copy and paste it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're encountering is related to how your Android device is trying to connect to your local server. When you use http://localhost, `http://127.0.0.1`, or `http://10.0.2.2`, the Android emulator interprets these as references to the emulator's own loopback network interface rather than your host machine's local server. This is why you see a different port number.

To solve this issue, you can use your host machine's IP address instead. Follow these steps:

1. Find your host machine's local IP address. You can use the command `ipconfig` in the command prompt (on Windows) or `ifconfig` (on macOS or Linux) to find it. Look for an IPv4 address (e.g., `192.168.1.x`).
2. Use this IP address in your Flutter app's code:
3. add Internet permission to manifest.xml

   final String baseUrl = 'http://your_host_machine_ip:80';

   final httpResponse = await http.get(Uri.parse('$baseUrl/yourAPI'));

Comment: I use a physical device. This address is used when we try to running applications in android emulator

Comment: your device should be connected to the same WIFI and it work fine

Answer (score 0):

**thank you everyone for your ideas!**
**I've find the solution.**

In my firewall Windows, I create a rule in order to open the port 80. Then, in the file httpd-vhosts.conf, i change "Require local" by "Require all granted".
Moreover, I use my ipv4 adress in my code.